# Why do I have an error in the declaration/definition? C++

Tags: c++

Good morning, Dear. I have the following configurations:
-Visual Studio (C++14 by default).

```
//main.cpp
#include "funciones.cpp"
int main() {
    myMsj();

    return 0;
}

//funciones.cpp
#include <iostream>
//Declaration
void myMsj(void);

//Definition
void myMsj(void) {
    std::cout << "llamada desde main\n";
}
```

**The compiler output:**
Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
Error   LNK2005 ya se definió "void __cdecl myMsj(void)" (?myMsj@@YAXXZ) en funciones.obj   prueba-1    C:...\prueba-1\main.obj 1

Error   LNK1169 se encontraron uno o más símbolos definidos simultáneamente prueba-1    C:...\prueba-1\x64\Debug\prueba-1.exe  1

---

I would like to clarify the following:
*This code compiled me Correctly in IDE Code::Block.

I don't compile in Visual Studio and Eclipse C/C++.
Why is this happening, dear?
Am I doing something that declaration/definition/call that is already deprecated in VSC/Eclipse?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `#include "funciones.cpp"` is a big no-no.  Never include a cpp file.

Comment: To fix this 1: create a header and put `void myMsj(void);` in it. 2: include this header from your 2 cpp files.

Comment: Fixed! As @NathaOliver mentioned: "Don't include the .cpp's, only include the .h's. My confusion arose because Code::block did compile correctly. I had a mistake in the theory. Thanks again.

Comment: ***My confusion arose because Code::block did compile correctly*** My guess is that the `funciones.cpp` file was not part of your Code::Blocks project. Many IDEs require you to add the source files you create to the project by using some menu item in the IDE. Just putting the files in the same folder as the project is not enough.

Answer (score -1):

The linker is complaining that it finds two definitions of the `myHsj()` function. This is probably because you are compiling both `main.cpp` and `funciones.cpp`, and then linking them together. Because in `main.cpp` you also include `funciones.cpp`, the compiler sees both `main.cpp` and `funciones.cpp` containing the `myHsj()` function.

The custom in C++ is to have a file called `funciones.hpp` (a so-called header file) that contains the function declaration, but not the definition. Then, both `funciones.cpp` and `main.cpp` can include `funciones.hpp`, while only `funciones.cpp` contains the definition. That should fix the error.